# Does calling GetDC directly create memory leaks?

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I am listening to the `ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()` msg, inside the fired function relative to that event called `OnEraseBackground(CDC* pDC)`. I am changing a background color like the following:

```
if (pDC)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(BlackColor);        
}
else if (GetDC())
{
    GetDC()->SetBkColor(BlackColor);            
}
```

My question is, should I call `ReleaseDC()` after `GetDC()`?

Comment: Err..., I do not understand the reason for overiding `OnEraseBackground` only to set the background color. For a custom window class, you can set it once (before creating the window) by using `AfxRegisterWndClass` to register a custom WindowClass having a specific background color...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A device context returned from [`GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) or [`CWnd::GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdc) should always be released by passing it either to [`ReleaseDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-releasedc) or [`CWnd::ReleaseDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#releasedc) (doesn't matter which one). The documentation is a fair bit lenient towards situations where this isn't strictly necessary, though establishing those preconditions is complex in itself.

If you call either of the `ReleaseDC` functions on a device context that doesn't strictly need to be released, the operation has no adverse effect.

The consequences of not releasing device contexts (a GDI resource) is *far* worse than a memory leak. GDI resources are severely limited, and shared across all processes running in the same user session. One program's GDI resource leak can easily cause any other program to malfunction.

Note that you are calling `GetDC` *twice* in your code so you will want to release it twice as well. Alternatively, only call it once, e.g.

```cpp
if (pDC)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(BlackColor);        
}
else
{
    auto myDC = GetDC();
    myDC->SetBkColor(BlackColor);
    ReleaseDC(myDC);
}
```

or, using an [`if` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) with initializer (introduced in C++17):

```cpp
if (pDC)
{
    pDC->SetBkColor(BlackColor);        
}
else if (auto myDC = GetDC())
{
    myDC->SetBkColor(BlackColor);
    ReleaseDC(myDC);
}
```

Though, really, I would probably just scrap the entire `else`-arm. If your `WM_ERASEBKGND` message handler doesn't receive a device context, then there's no reason to go hunting for one yourself.

Answer (score 5):

### Win32 API

According to this article for [`GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) it states:

> After painting with a common DC, the `ReleaseDC` function *must be called* to release the DC. **Class** and **private** DCs *do not* have to be released. `ReleaseDC` must be called from the same thread that called `GetDC`. The number of DCs is limited only by available memory.

---

### `CWnd`

If it is a [`CWnd::GetDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#getdc) then:

> Unless the device context belongs to a window class, the `ReleaseDC` member function *must be called* to release the context after painting.

---

Under normal circumstances you would do this:

```
CDC *pDC = GetDC();
if (pDC != nullptr)
{
   pDC->SomeFunc(...);
}
// etc..
```

The linked article refers to some samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/drawing-with-the-mouse).

Does that help?

Comment: yes,thanks the article cleared a lot for ambiguous stuff for me